# I need dashboard with TreeView in Vue

Tags: vue.js, treeview, dashboard

*I need dashboard with TreeView .I don't found good example in google. Can anyone recommend me any git hub link.*

Comment: Please make some minimal effort here.

Answer (score 1):

I created a dynamic treeView dashboard in vue with [gridstack](https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js) in a closed source project I suggest you checking it out